# How to configure Login page which is develope in Angular 2 with spring spring security

Tags: java, angular, spring-security

i created login app using Angular 2 and Spring Security. here i created login page using Angular2 and kept in app folder. when i click on Button for submit form then it will call the getLogin() method which is defined in login.componet.ts file. here i am calling service. but i am getting status code 0. as follows 
    EXCEPTION: Response with status: 0  for URL: null
    main.bundle.js:545Response with status: 0  for URL: null

```
<form id="login-form" class="login-form" (submit)="login()" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="email"placeholder="Email Address" [(ngModel)]="username">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password">
        <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
        <button class="btn" type="submit" value="">SIGN IN</button>
</form>
```

Login.component.ts

```
login():void {
        console.log("Username :"+this.username+" Password :"+this.password);
        this.service.getLogin(this.username,this.password).subscribe(lst             console.log(lst));
      }"
```

Service :

```
getLogin(username,password):Observable<string> {
        let body = new URLSearchParams();
        body.set('username', username);
        body.set('password', password);
        let response = this.http.post(`${AppSettings.BACK_ENDPOINT}/login`,body);
        console.log("=======LoginService=======");
        return response.map(isAuthenticated);
      }

    }
    function isAuthenticated(response:Response):string {
      return response.json();
    }



 When client logged in successfully then Spring Security returning defaultSeccessURl and should redirect to that default success url.
    but its not happening when calling by calling above service
Please help me.
```

Comment: please put your spring controller , and console.log ${AppSettings.BACK_ENDPOINT}

Comment: AppSettings.BACK_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:8080/myapp and for controller spring security internally map then "/login"